# Update one property's value to the value of another property in the same document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How can we replicate the following sql query in MongoDb?

```
update Person set Alias = Name;
```

where the `Person` table has the columns `Alias, Name`

I want the query to affect multiple rows. It doesn't matter if the update query cannot support upserts, I only need to update & not insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that functionality is not available in MongoDB.  You will need to loop through the documents, updating them one-at-a-time, and doing a read-update pair.

If you want this to be concurrency-safe, you'll need to implement some sort of locking; either optimistic or pessimistic.

Comment: Thought so. I will keep the question open for a while though, just in case someone is able to offer some insight that I not seeing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
myDb.myCollection.find({}).forEach(
function (person) { 
      person.Alias = person.Name
      myDb.myCollection.save(person)
}
)
```

Comment: Not quite. This would in reality make 1 select query and `n` update queries for `n` person documents. I am looking for something that does 1 update query.